# Can we trigger Full GC manually or with parameter at some percent of heap, is that suggestible

Tags: java, image-processing, garbage-collection, jvm, heap-memory

I am working on digital image processing. when I tried with higher resolution images with load, I am getting lot OOM issues.

I am using these startup parameters with application

```
-Xms10240m -Xmx10240m -XX:NewRatio=3 -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=80 -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps
```

I cannot affordable to increase heap memory.

So, can I trigger Full manually at some percentage of heap, If possible.
running manual is suggestible operation ??

Comment: A garbage collect is not going to help you with an OOM..

Comment: GC is always done before an `OOM` is thrown, so you just don't have enough memory. Either get more memory or modify your program to use less memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a request to the JVM to trigger GC using a call to System.gc().  The API docs say that this, "suggests that the Java Virtual Machine expend effort toward recycling unused objects".  If you are using the HotSpot JVM from Oracle then it will run a full GC every time you call it.

However, this is unlikely (as has been said in the comments) to solve your problem.  The GC is very good at reclaiming space that is no longer needed so the OOM exception you're getting is most likely due to the fact that you only have 1Gb of memory for your heap.  How big are your images and how many are you trying to process simultaneously?  You should be able to do some simple maths to work out the minimum size of heap you require.

You have the following two arguments:

```
-XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=80
```

This means the JVM Is waiting until the heap is 80% full before initiating the concurrent collector.  Try lowering this.  No guarantees, but it may improve things.